# React state undefined inside a fetch

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, state, undefined

I am new to react and I have a problem inside one of my fetch:
I get the response with axios and the response is formatted.

console.log(formattedResponse) is a jsonObject
but the state I set with the same variable like this: setSelectedStatParams(formattedResponse) is undefined

I tried to console.log it at another place in my code but it is always undefined...

I really do not understand why.. The state selectedStatParams is used in the JSX for a map and it works .. But console.log is always undefined.

Can you help me to understand that ?

Thanks in advance :)

```
  const handleStatSelection = (statisticId) => {
    setIsLoadingStatSelection(true);
    axios.get(statsApiUrl + "/filters/" + statisticId)
      .then(response => {
        const antennaParentSuggIndex = response.data.parentSuggestions.findIndex(parentSugg => parentSugg.parentSuggId === 873);
        let formattedResponse = response.data;
        formattedResponse.parentSuggestions[antennaParentSuggIndex].childSuggestions = response.data.parentSuggestions[antennaParentSuggIndex].childSuggestions.map((childSugg) => {
          //uncheck the unselected Antenna 
          if (childSugg.value !== auth.antenna) {
            childSugg.isActiveCheckBox = 0;
          }
          return childSugg;
        });
        setSelectedStatParams(formattedResponse);
        console.log(formattedResponse)
        console.log(selectedStatParams)
        //by default the first result type is the first
        if (selectedStatParams?.resultsTypes.length > 0) {
          setResultType(selectedStatParams.resultsTypes[0]);
          setFixedDate(end);
        } else {
          setResultType(null);
        }
        selectedStatParams && fetchStatResult(statisticId)
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setIsLoadingStatSelection(false));
  };
```

Comment: setting state is kindda async operation so updated thing will be available after next cycle. So I would suggest use`formattedResponse` instead of `selectedStatParams`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using useEffect, the state has been updated.

```
const handleStatSelection = (statisticId) => {
  setIsLoadingStatSelection(true);
  axios.get(statsApiUrl + "/filters/" + statisticId)
    .then(response => {
      const antennaParentSuggIndex = response.data.parentSuggestions.findIndex(parentSugg => parentSugg.parentSuggId === 873);
      let formattedResponse = response.data;
      formattedResponse.parentSuggestions[antennaParentSuggIndex].childSuggestions = response.data.parentSuggestions[antennaParentSuggIndex].childSuggestions.map((childSugg) => {
        if (childSugg.value !== auth.antenna) {
          childSugg.isActiveCheckBox = 0;
        }
        return childSugg;
      });

      setSelectedStatParams(formattedResponse);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
    .finally(() => setIsLoadingStatSelection(false));
};

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(selectedStatParams);
  if (selectedStatParams?.resultsTypes.length > 0) {
    setResultType(selectedStatParams.resultsTypes[0]);
    setFixedDate(end);
  } else {
    setResultType(null);
  }

  selectedStatParams && fetchStatResult(statisticId);
}, [selectedStatParams]); // Run the effect whenever selectedStatParams changes
```